# How to output unicode characters and lines into an image file?

Tags: python, image, unicode, jpeg

I want to create a jpg or any other image format files for chinese characters, how do i do it?

My input textfile (in utf8) looks like this:

```
阿贝•斯兰尼\t是\t美国人
```

Reading it is simple, i could simply do `codecs.open('intext.txt','r','utf8).read().strip().split('\t')` but how can I output an image file that looks like this:
[image]

Eventually, the whole jpg might look like this:
[image]

So the exact questions are:

1. How do I output connecting lines into an image file using python?
2. How do I output unicode characters into an image file using python?
3. How do I output both connecting lines and unicode in a structured order into an image file using python? (i.e. progressively create the first image to create a tree like image like the second image)

Comment: `"in a structured order"` What do you mean by this? `"progressively create the first image to create a tree"` this still doesn't quite make sense; you have to keep track of all the points where things should intersect and draw the lines so they intersect there. Or do you want a ready-made tree class that generates exactly your expected output? (this probably doesn't exist)

Comment: I suppose you could recursively work on smaller sections of the image and use a generic "draw two labelled lines and an arc" method on that subimage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) (the Python Imaging Library) can both draw lines and unicode text to images, using the [ImageDraw](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagedraw.htm) module. For your text to be printed correctly, you'll have to ensure that you've got a unicode string (not utf-8 encoded) and a font which contains the characters you want to display.

To [create a new image](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.new):

```
image = Image.new('RGB', (xsize, ysize))
```

To get a [draw instance for that image](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagedraw.htm#tag-ImageDraw.Draw):

```
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
```

To [draw text](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagedraw.htm#tag-ImageDraw.Draw.text):

```
draw.text((xpos,ypos), mytext, font=ImageFont.truetype('myfont.ttf', 11))
```

To [draw a line](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagedraw.htm#tag-ImageDraw.Draw.line):

```
draw.line((startx,starty, endx,endy), fill=128)
```

To [draw an arc](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagedraw.htm#tag-ImageDraw.Draw.arc):

```
draw.arc((startx,starty, endx,endy), startangle, endangle)
```

Comment: how do i create a new image with PIL? I've looked high and low for tutorials but all it gives is an image editing stuff not image creation...